# What is the behavior of concurrent requests to S3 Operations with Disconnects?

Tags: amazon-s3, concurrency

Suppose a client issues a request to delete an object and before a response is received, that client is disconnected. Now suppose a put request for the same key is issued and completes.

1. Is it possible that the first delete operation now executes after the put succeeds, giving what seems like corruption? My current understanding is that S3 behavior is undefined with concurrent requests like this, but I couldn't find any more specific information.
2. More generally how are concurrent requests handled in S3 if client disconnect after their initial request phase?

To be clear, I'm interested in the behavior of the above when a second request is made and would complete before the first request has a chance to complete.

Answer (score 1):

There are two topics to discuss here:

1. The consistency model of S3
2. The behavior of an API call when the client disconnects after sending the request

Firstly, the consistency model of S3 is [well-documented](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/Welcome.html#ConsistencyModel) and even addresses the case of concurrent calls:

> In the last example, W2 begins before W1 has received an
> acknowledgment. Therefore, these writes are considered concurrent.
> Amazon S3 internally uses last-writer-wins semantics to determine
> which write takes precedence. 
> However, the order in which Amazon S3
> receives the requests and the order in which applications receive
> acknowledgments cannot be predicted because of various factors, such
> as network latency. 
> For example, W2 might be initiated by an Amazon
> EC2 instance in the same Region, while W1 might be initiated by a host
> that is farther away. 
> **The best way to determine the final value is to
> perform a read after both writes have been acknowledged.**

As for the second topic, it's not really a matter concerning the server (or S3, in this case). 
If the client disconnects before sending the request, the request is not sent. 
However, if the client disconnects after sending the request, the server will still receive it. 
The client will need to refresh the data upon reconnection, and if it tries to perform an action that's inconsistent with the server's state, the server will block it.